# Alignment the author in article (More Left) *Duplicated*

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{\Large{\noindent Charge Density and Charge Per Phase as Cofactors in Neural Injury Induced by Electrical Stimulation\vspace{-2ex}}}}
\date{}
\author{\normalsize{DOUGLAS B. McCREERY, WILLIAM F. AGNEW, TED G. H. YUEN, AND LEO BULLARA}}
\maketitle
\newpage
\end{document}
```

The title and author should be in center but only the title has a correct position!
What can I do?
Thanks for your helping !

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks,I dont know how to post exactly,Thanks for some friend(Editing)! :)

Comment: @Johannes_B It's about figure but I have some words,there isn't any package or something else that i can manage the exact postition of title and author(instead of titling!)

Comment: @AMiRhosein: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I appreciate You Man! I Got it! Thanks A lot!

Comment: @AMiRhosein: You should thank Johannes_B, not me :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B What's makebox and textwidth[c],Textworks can't compile this line?,thanks!

Comment: I wrote nonsense above, sorry. I'll delete the comments in a bit.

Comment: You should not have any formatting commands in `\uthor` and `\title` they are supposed to just take _text_ with teh formatting specified by the class in the definition of `\maketitle` using `\Large` in that way is particular;y wrong: it does not take an argument so should be `\Large ...` not `\large{...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no formatting in `\author` or `\title` these commands just collect *text* which is then formatted by `\maketitle` according to the rules set by the class or preamble commands.

The author list was being set incorrectly as it was marked up as a *single* author so `\maketitle` set it on a single line. Multiple authors should be separated by `\and`.  Also there is no `a4` option to `article` it should be `a4paper`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}

\begin{document}
\title{Charge Density and Charge Per Phase as Cofactors in Neural Injury Induced by Electrical Stimulation}
\date{}
\author{DOUGLAS B. McCREERY\and
WILLIAM F. AGNEW\and
 TED G. H. YUEN\and
LEO BULLARA}
\maketitle
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know what you mean but I saw a lot of paper in IEEE that we has many author,in addition they are in a unique line! by accident I'm so beginner in LATEX Coding and I'm so interested that what do they do in this line!